# Using private constructors for factory methods?

Tags: java, immutability, private-constructor

Let's say I'm building an immutable Yahtzee scorecard class:

```
public final class Scorecard {

    private Map<Category, Integer> scorecard = new HashMap<Category, Integer>();

    public Scorecard() {
        // Instantiates a new empty scorecard
    }

    private Scorecard(Map<Category, Integer> scorecard) {
        this.scorecard = scorecard;
    }

    public Scorecard withScore(Category category, int[] roll) {
        newScorecard = new HashMap<Category, Integer>(scorecard); // Pretend that this is a deep-copy
        newScorecard.put(category, calculateScoreFromRoll(roll));
        return new Scorecard(newScorecard);
    }

    public int getScore(Category category) {
        return scorecard.get(category);
    }

}
```

Basically I don't want to expose the internals of the class. If I didn't have a private constructor then I would need to use a public constructor with a `Map` argument just like the private one (and I could essentialy lose the `withScore()` method too) in order to allow scoring. But is this a valid way of doing factory methods?

Comment: It sounds like what you're talking about is more of a Builder than a Factory, but yes, this is a fine approach.

Comment: @chrylis Would you say that factory methods should not built upon existing instances?

Comment: I can't make any sense of that question.

Answer (score 9):

A very common, and good pattern is to have all private constructors and public static factory methods:

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyClass() {}
    public static MyClass fromA(A foo) {
        MyClass o = new MyClass();
        o.field = bar; // etc
        return o;
    }
    public static MyClass fromB(B foo) {
        MyClass o = new MyClass();
        o.field = bar; // etc
        return o;
    }
}
```

Note: This allows different factory methods with the same parameter types, which constructors do not allow.

Comment: A *possible* problem with this pattern is that it does not allow subclassing. If you do not want to allow it in first place, set the class to `final` to indicate that. If you want to allow it, use a protected constructor and consider setting the class as `abstract` if it warrens sublassing.

Comment: @user1803551 Unfortunately, final classes interfere with a number of AOP and other reflection-based techniques (one Spring feature breaks if a method returns `String`), so it's not as easy to recommend as it was five years ago.

Comment: @chrylis I was not aware of this. However, a private constructor in a non-final method allows an inner class to subclass its parent class. I assume this is the only case to recommend `final`?

Comment: @user1803551  Private constructor is not required - make it protected if it makes sense to allow subclassing, but you lose control of construction via factory methods. Making class final is not necessary or even desirable if constructors are private, because a) it's code clutter; it's obvious if constructor is private that you don't want to allow subclassing, and b) you might want to create a subclass inside the class, either an anonymous class or proper inner class.

Answer (score 1):

Factory methods are intended to allow you to get an object without specifying the exact type.

For example, from Effective Java, 2nd edition:

> The class java.util.EnumSet (Item 32), introduced in release 1.5, has no public constructors, only static factories. They return one of two implementations, depending on the size of the underlying enum type: if it has sixty-four or fewer elements, as most enum types do, the static factories return a RegularEnumSet instance, which is backed by a single long; if the enum type has sixty-five or more elements, the factories return a JumboEnumSet instance, backed by a long array.
>
> The existence of these two implementation classes is invisible to clients. If RegularEnumSet ceased to offer performance advantages for small enum types, it could be eliminated from a future release with no ill effects. Similarly, a future release could add a third or fourth implementation of EnumSet if it proved benefi- cial for performance. Clients neither know nor care about the class of the object they get back from the factory; they care only that it is some subclass of EnumSet.

Using constructors instead of static methods like you suggested breaks the factory method pattern, because by using the constructor directly you are specifying an implementation.

In your case, if you want to use a factory method you would make the default constructor private so clients could not directly instantiate a `ScoreCard`. At this point, you're free to use whatever specific implementation of `ScoreCard` in the factory method. For example, if you make a second `ScoreCard` class that is backed with a `TreeMap`, you can switch which implementation of `ScoreCard` that the client gets just by changing the static factory.

Comment: That's true for an *abstract* factory method, not a factory method.

Comment: I was under the impression that this is the static factory pattern, because this uses static methods, while an abstract factory pattern is having an interface define the methods and you write the object that picks the implementation... But even then, is just a regular factory method distinct from the above two kinds?

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong; it describes an abstract factory method, not a factory method. A factory method returns a known type, which is what this question is about. An abstract factory method returns an implementation of a abstract type (eg an interface or abstract class) without the caller knowing what exact type will be returned.

Comment: Seems like I learned the nomenclature differently... Effective Java says "A third advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike constructors, they can return an object of any subtype of their return type. This gives you great flexibility in choosing the class of the returned object", and I learned something similar to that, where an abstract factory was an interface that you can implement in multiple different ways, allowing you to pick the implementation at runtime, whereas a static factory had the implementation picked at compile time.

Comment: We are not talking about factories here. We are talking about factory methods. Related topic, but not to this question.

Comment: I'm getting confused now... Josh Bloch writes one thing, you say another, and it appears I'm starting to conflate the factories that I learned with the methods they implement. I'll do some reading around...